# Unity spriteRenderer error what i need to do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i dont know what this means...

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.common@4.1.0\Runtime\InternalBridge\InternalEngineBridge.cs(21,35): error CS1061: 'SpriteRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'IsUsingDeformableBuffer' and no accessible extension method 'IsUsingDeformableBuffer' accepting a first argument of type 'SpriteRenderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: mostly likely , you missing method ''IsUsingDeformableBuffer'' , that accept 'SpriteRenderer' within the method, be sure you have all the files downloaded or coped correctly.

Comment: Happened for me while downgrading unity from 2021 to 2020. As the answers are suggesting: removing and installing the 2D Animation package in the package manager did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I have the solution for this problem. Just got to PackageManager, type 2D remove all, and install it again!

Answer (score 4):

I removed 2d animation package from package manager and it worked for me.

Comment: Might also consider the need to remove PSD Importer -- that worked for me which effectively also removed 2D animator (dependent on PSD). Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the 2D PSD importer to the verified version 4.1.3 works in my case

Comment: This is great - worked for me as well. This PSD importer was a dependency that had to be removed first! After this my unity crashed, but when I reopened it was installed and fixed my issues. Gracias!